# Unable to execute npm commands :Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: javascript, npm, installation

node version :v14.16.1
λ npm -v
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
6.14.12
Getting this error after install the above node version
npm at the command prompt is not working giving the below error:

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Can anyone suggest a solution, is this the problem with the node/npm versions.